# Display something on admin post page if specific category is selected

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to get Wordpress' Admin Post Page to display some form of output when a specific category (say, 'Featured') is selected.

Something like this (original page):

[image: original-image]

When I select the 'Featured' category (selected 'Featured' category), I want something to display, like this:

[image: when-selected]

Meaning the page checks if the specific category is checked, and if it is, Wordpress generates an option menu for the user to fill in.

How do I go about doing this? I'm looking at the Wordpress Codex but so far, no dice.

Comment: can you please elaborate what do you want to display?

Comment: like an options menu, extra fields, anything!

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to print some jQuery *only in that screen*, and then it's matter of listening for live changes and making the show/hide actions.

The following is from [this WPSE Answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53486/how-to-add-or-remove-metabox-each-page-separately/53557#53557). You have to adjust the elements IDs. Also, jQuery's `live` method is [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/), change that as well.

```
add_action('admin_head', 'wpse_53486_script_enqueuer');
function wpse_53486_script_enqueuer() {
    global $current_screen;
    if ( 'post' == $current_screen->id ) 
    {
        echo <<<HTML
            <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
                if ( $('#in-category-6').is(':checked') ) {
                    $("form#adv-settings label[for='myplugin_sectionid-hide']").show();
                    $('#myplugin_sectionid').show();
                } else {
                    $('#myplugin_sectionid').hide();
                    $("form#adv-settings label[for='myplugin_sectionid-hide']").hide();
                }

                $('#in-category-6').live('change', function(){
                    if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
                        $('#myplugin_sectionid').show();
                        $("form#adv-settings label[for='myplugin_sectionid-hide']").show();
                    } else {
                        $('#myplugin_sectionid').hide();
                        $("form#adv-settings label[for='myplugin_sectionid-hide']").hide();
                    }
                });                 
            });    
            </script>
HTML;
    }
}
```

Another method to print scripts in [targeted admin pages](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/36121/12615).

Answer (score 0):

If you want that you feature will works after the post is saved (so that it already marked id DB to witch category this post belong to), you should use `in_category()` function to detect whether this post is in the category that you want, and if so - to show your extra box.
But, as I understand you want that it will work also before the post is saved, so you should use jQuery - detect whether the checkbox with value x (where x is your category id) is checked, and then display your extra box by changing css `display` property from `none` to `block`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/).

It is a wordpress plugin that allows you to add additional fields to posts, and it can do this by category. I have used it before to set background images on posts for use in a slider.

Comment: problem is, I don't want to depend on ACF's functionality for my plugin :( thanks for the help though.